# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - What's the difference between the Java platform and the Tomcat platform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Our programmers are currently switching our code over to Springboot. They gave me a .war file and if I deploy it in Elastic Beanstalk and select the "Tomcat" platform it will come up and work. If I select the "Java" platform our site will not work.

I want to understand what is happening in the background. When I select "Tomcat" is Elastic Beanstalk spinning up and configuring tomcat automatically for me and installing our .war to use it?

What about when Java is selected? What will be the servlet container and how is it set up? Is it trying to set up Nginx when Java is selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.html):

> AWS Elastic Beanstalk supports two platforms for Java applications.
>
> Tomcat – A platform based on Apache Tomcat, an open source web
> container for applications that use Java servlets and JavaServer Pages
> (JSPs) to serve HTTP requests. Tomcat facilitates web application
> development by providing multithreading, declarative security
> configuration, and extensive customization. Elastic Beanstalk has
> platform branches for each of Tomcat's current major versions. For
> more information, see The Tomcat platform.
>
> Java SE – A platform for applications that don't use a web container,
> or use one other than Tomcat, such as Jetty or GlassFish. You can
> include any library Java Archives (JARs) used by your application in
> the source bundle that you deploy to Elastic Beanstalk. For more
> information, see The Java SE platform.

To answer your question:

> I want to understand what is happening in the background. When I
> select "Tomcat" is Elastic Beanstalk spinning up and configuring
> tomcat automatically for me and installing our .war to use it?

Yes that's exactly what Elastic Beanstalk is doing.

> What about when Java is selected? What will be the servlet container
> and how is it set up? Is it trying to set up Nginx when Java is
> selected?

It is expecting you to provide a Java deployment artifact that does not depend on Tomcat, such as a Spring Boot runnable Jar.

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thank you!!